# Absolute values of a linear combination of three random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

From my stat homework: with $X \sim N(3.2, 6.5)$, $Y \sim N(-2.1,3.5)$, $Z \sim N(12.0,7.5)$ (all are independent random variables) find probability that:
$$
|X + 6Y + Z| \geq  2
$$
I have $(X + 6Y + Z) \sim N(2.6, 140)$.

When I convert 2 into standard distribution ($Z$), I get ($-0.0507$).
The book gives an answer of $P(|X + 6Y + Z| \geq 2) = 0.8689$.
How do I go about solving this? I can't make any sense of an absolute value being greater than a negative number.

Answer (score 2):

For any random variable $U$ and constant $a>0$:
$$
P(|U|\geq a)=P(U\leq -a)+P(U\geq a).
$$